# Better way to add attribute to collection

Tags: magento

I am overriding the Mage/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php and adding some data to the prepareCollection.  This is how I got the customer EAV Attribute campaign_id to be included in the collection, but it is kind of hacky.  I was wondering if there was a better way.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    foreach ($collection as &$object){
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setId($object->getCustomerId())
            ->load();
        $object->setCampaignId($customer->getCampaignId());

    }
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with this data? Are you also adding a column to display?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to join the data from customer records onto the order collection before its loaded.

You can observe the collection before & after load events. For `sales/order_grid_collection` collection these events are `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` and `sales_order_grid_collection_load_after` - you'll want to use the former. The collection can be accessed in your `_before_load` event observer via `$observer->getOrderGridCollection()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected function _prepareCollection() {

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $class = get_class($collection);
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')
                ->getAttribute('customer', 'campaign_id');
    $attributeId = $attribute->getAttributeId();
    $backendType = $attribute->getBackendType();  //probably varchar

    $tableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
            ->getTableName('customer_entity_' . $backendType);

    $collection->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(array('v' => $tableName),
                        'main_table.customer_id = v.entity_id AND attribute_id = 153',
                        array('v.value', 'v.attribute_id'));

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }
```

Comment: I'm hoping the same thing..  If you have a better solution, I'd love to see it.

Comment: I posted a more flexible solution above as an answer. Use an event observer on `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` event to bang on the fields you need. This is the primary utility of auto-fired events in Magento collection classes.